# surface area when the curve is revolved about the x-axis

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

find the surface area when the curve is revolved about the x-axis

Steps so far:
$y=\sqrt{4x+3}$ on $[0,3]$
$$S=\int_{a}^{b} 2π \left(f(x)\right)\sqrt{1+f'(x)^2} $$
$$S=\int_{a}^{b} 2π \left(\sqrt{4x+3}\right)\sqrt{1+(\frac{2}{\sqrt{4x+3}})^2} dx $$
$$S=\int_{a}^{b} 2π \left(\sqrt{4x+3}\right)\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{4x+3}} dx$$
I get stuck here, I hope someone can guide through this problem

Comment: $y^2=4\left (x+\frac{3}{4}\right )$ is a parabola with vertex at $\left (0,-\frac{3}{4}\right )$. Just find the surface area of paraboloid formed by rotating $y^2=4x$ in $\left [0,\frac{15}{4}\right ]$ and subtract the surface area of the same paraboloid in the interval $\left [0,-\frac{3}{4}\right ]$

Comment: @AvZ wait I am confused now

Comment: The paraboloid formed $y^2=4x$ has same surface area as $y=\frac{x^2}{4}$ if you like working with $x$...

Comment: @AvZ so would the answer be $2(8\sqrt{6}-4\sqrt{3})\pi$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just need to do a little extra algebra. Notice that $$\begin{align}\left(\sqrt{4x+3}\right)\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{4x+3}} = \sqrt{(4x+3)\left(1+\frac{4}{4x+3}\right)} \\ = \sqrt{(4x+3)\cdot 1+\frac{4(4x+3)}{4x+3}}  \\ = \sqrt{4x+7}\end{align}$$ And hence $$2\pi\int_{0}^{3} \left(\sqrt{4x+3}\right)\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{4x+3}} dx = 2\pi\int_{0}^{3}\sqrt{4x+7} dx$$ This remaining quantity should be readily solvable with a $u$-sub.

Comment: totally got it now. thanks a lot